# $N$-Queens Discrete

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So with a $n\times n$ board, $n^2$ variables $p(i,j)$ for $i = 1, 2, ..., n$ and $j = 1, 2, ..., n$.

The book says if the squares are on the same diagonal $(i,j)$ and $(i', j')$ if $i+i' = j+j'$ or if $i-i' = j-j'$.

But when you have $p(3,4)$ and $p(5,4)$

$3+5=8$

$4+4 = 8$

but those points are not on the same diagonal? What am I misinterpreting?

[image: Text]

Comment: I think that in the context of your book $i' \ne i$.

Comment: Never post unsearchable images of text.  Instead take the time to typeset it in *MathJax*.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one error in the text you posted; $(i,j)$ and $(i',j')$ are on the same diagonal if $i+i'=j+j'$ or $i-i'=j-j'$.  For example, $(1,2)$ is on the same diagonal (a "difference diagonal") as $(2,3)$ since $1-2=-1=2-3$.  Also $(1,2)$ is on the same diagonal (a "sum diagonal") as $(2,1)$ since $1+2=3=2+1$.

Without more of the text, I cannot be absolutely sure what "p(6,2) and p(2,1) are true" and "p(3,4) and p(5,4) are false" means.  I suspect that it means that if opposing queens were on p(6,2) and p(2,1), they would not attack each other, but opposing queens on p(3,4) and p(5,4) would attack each other.